# Cannot Move Object That is Keyframed

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a sphere in my scene, and I keyframe its position. However, I later decide to change its position on that keyframe, so I go back to the keyframe in question, and attempt to move the object. I cannot. It seems that Blender will not let me move an object on an existing keyframe. Is there a setting I am missing? Also I cannot adjust it's position between two keyframes to add a new one in the middle. It seems as though setting a keyframe locks it in stone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Select the existing keyframe you wanna remove and press 'x' -> delete keyframe

Comment: maybe share your file (or just an object/armature that doesn't work anymore): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the key frames and clean them or you have to delete them and place the object in desired position and then add the key frames.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well, I had a dynamic paint modifier on the object. I removed that modifier, and like magic, i could move the object and key it again on the same frame. Looks like it may have just been a bug. I was using a beta version. I switched to the latest stable and I no longer have the problem. :) thanks for your tips